# Pandas bar graph for huge data group x axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

i have a a table in pandas data frame which contains 2 columns

```
+----------+------------+
|        id| orders     |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 1100       |
| 2        | 22753      |
| 3        | 34         |
| 4        | 11         |
| 5        | 430        |
| 6        | 1175       |

| ...      | ..         | 
| 800      | 17         |
+----------+------------+
```

i want to plot a bar graph where i want x axis bars ranging from

1-100,100-200,200-300 and so on till 700-800,

and respective total orders in y axis

please help me, i am using

matplotlib.pyplot package for this.

i tried running this code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 6)) # Create matplotlib figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes

width = 0.2

df.orders.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

occurances is by mistake,consider it as orders
[image: occurances is by mistake,consider it as orders]

Comment: df.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1). Can you try this ?

Comment: @Backtrack i tried that but on x axis i am having seperate bars from 1to 800 which is not proper, i want it in groups like 1-100, 100-200 and so on

Comment: You should create a new `dataframe` then, which has 8 rows and the corresponding sums of orders.

Comment: @jbndlr sir, see i have added the image too, can you please tell me how do i do that? new dataframe with 8 rows from my previous df

Comment: plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df.id), max(df.id)+100, 100.0)). SOme thing like this

Comment: @ShubhamRingne, You have to set the xticks.

Comment: @Backtrack, sir i created ax which is subplot of plt.fig and i am unable to do xticks on that **(ax.xticks)**  i am getting error  **'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `DataFrame` that holds the aggregated information to be plotted. For this example, I use randomly generated data:

```
# Build example DataFrame
n_ids = 800
ids = []
ods = []
for i in range(1, n_ids + 1):
    ids.append(i)
    ods.append(random.randint(5, 20000))

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'orders': ods})
```

This dataframe has the same structure as yours. Using a `chunk_size` of `100` (as you asked for), you can easily calculate the chunk (or *group*) each `id` belongs to and aggregate the `orders` using `sum()`:

```
# Group by chunks
chunk_size = 100

# Add new column 'chunk' to describe groups
df['chunk'] = [int((i - 1) / chunk_size) + 1 for i in df['id']]
# Group, aggregate and store as new DataFrame
pdf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['chunk'])['orders'].sum())
```

The new `DataFrame` called `pdf` then looks like this:

```
        orders
chunk         
1       937595
2       987138
3      1109390
4      1097058
5      1039206
6      1060363
7       999461
8      1086585
```

Now, you can simply plot the aggregated values as you tried before:

```
# Plot aggregates
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

width = 0.2

pdf.orders.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Cheers.